# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'?

Tags: android, android-studio

Am getting en error while try to run the project

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$PrintHelperStubImpl.class

Here is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codecanyon.khalyil"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true


        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

i tried by cleaning the project

Build - > Clean

after that rebuild, But no effect

The i sync and clean the project, still no result.

Finally i click on 'build apk', but the issue still exciting.

Can any one please help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a class that is included in two dependencies. This is most likely the v4 support lib. Check if one of your dependencies dont include the v4 support library which you already include yourself. You can exclude a dependency this way:

```
compile ('com.somesdk:sdk:1.3.5@aar') {
    transitive=true //you dont need this if you use jars or non-aar dependencies
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```